# Shared affiliations for multiple authors with unique label in revtex

Tags: revtex, affiliation, multiple-citations

I would like to give a unique label to each author and affiliation in revtex, so to use them as I wish without repetitions.

The article class offers the \affil command within the authblk package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Article Title}

\author[1,2]{D. Duck}
\author[2,3]{M. Mouse}
\author[1,4]{H. Simpson}

\affil[1]{Duckburg} 
\affil[2]{Mouseton} 
\affil[3]{Disneyland} 
\affil[4]{Springfield}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is an article.
\end{document}
```

But when switching to revtex I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@affil already defined.
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\makeatletter
\let\c@affil\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Article Title}
[...]
```

Comment: The compilation goes through but there's no title in the output.
In the log file:
    Class revtex4 Warning: No title.

Comment: I see. I suppose that class `revtex4` and package `authblk` are incompatible, because `rectex4` has a lot of commands for affiliations and so on.